# Как установить время начала и окончания воспроизведения живого видео в ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3

*Привет, у меня есть телешоу в прямом эфире, которое начинается в 08:00 и заканчивается в 10:00, могу ли я установить время начала и окончания телешоу для DefaultTimeBar?*
Я пробовал :

```
exoPlayerProgress.setDuration(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000)
```

и

```
MediaItem.Builder()
.setUri(mUrl)
.setLiveConfiguration(
    MediaItem.LiveConfiguration.Builder()
        .setMaxPlaybackSpeed(1.02f)
        .setTargetOffsetMs(System.currentTimeMillis()+200000)
        .build()
)
.setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
.build()
```